# Mapping a SharePoint list item to a C# class

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Say I have:

```
public class SPListItem
{ 
     public override object this[string fieldName]
     {
       get
       {
         return this.GetValue(fieldName);
       }
       set
       {
         this.SetValue(fieldName, value, !this.HasExternalDataSource);
       }
     }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; } 
    public int Prop2 { get; set; } 
    public int Prop3 { get; set; } 
}
```

is there any way I can do:

```
var fooInst = new SPListItem();
Bar barInst = (Bar)fooInst // or maybe Bar.FromFoo(Foo f) if handling the cast is not possible
```

and then have:

`barInst.Prop1` give me the equivalent of:

`fooInst["Prop"];`

Without implementing the getters and setters for every property in Bar?

Comment: Can you explain in your question text what problem you are trying to solve? You cannot cast if it doesn't inherit nor provide an explicit conversion operator, so you will have to map the properties one way or another. AutoMapper can do that for you.

Comment: [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) does just that...

Comment: This is the wrong question and has nothing to do with casting. What you are asking is how to copy a POCO's values to a *SharePoint* server-side SPListItem object. Neither Expando, nor any other object are going to help. The field names probably are *not* named the same as the properties. Why don't use use LINQ to SharePoint to define the mappings?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. What I'd like to do is Auto-generate my model, and populate it from an SPListItem object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Haha of course they are. I just read the XML files from the VS project while generating the code :P

Comment: *Is* this a SharePoint question? You should tag it this way and make clear what you want to do. If it *is*, first, you could use LINQ to SP to retrieve the objects. If you don't want to do this, you should note that field names are almost certainly different from the property names. You'll need to store the mappings somewhere

Comment: @David I don't think you realize that in SharePoint, even the field names in your *site definition* aren't guaranteed to be the same *in the site itself*. If there is another field with the same name during deployment, the Display name will be the same but the field name will change

Comment: Anyway, why don't you use LINQ to SP ?

Comment: I'll research into Linq to SP, maybe I'm taking the wrong approach, however I think I've made the question is generic enough to not be related to SharePoint. `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee535491(v=office.14).aspx` -> ` Where is <Customer> defined?

Comment: `Display name will be the same but the field name will change`. I'm using internal names. Are you sure internal names change?

Comment: There is nothing generic about SharePoint. The devil *is* in the details. There isn't even a PropertyBag involved - the field values may or may not be loaded in their entirety in a server-side object, but may result in queries all the way to the database as you request them

Comment: Anyway, the point is - SharePoint questions should be properly tagged, including the version.

Comment: Ok you're right. I've made it sharepoint specific now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaaand, here we go. This class generates entities from your lists.
From: https://justsharepointthings.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/sharepoint-generate-c-poco-classes-from-an-existing-definition/

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Code_Generation {
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates List object entities from a site connection.
    /// </summary>
    public class SPListPocoGenerator {
        string parentDir = "GeneratedListPOCO/";
        string hiddenDir = "GeneratedListPOCO/HiddenLists/";

        private class PropertyString {
            private string _propStr;

            public PropertyString(string propStr) {
                _propStr = propStr;
                _properties = new Dictionary < string, string > ();
            }

            private Dictionary < string, string > _properties;
            public string this[string key] {
                get {
                    return _properties.ContainsKey(key) ? _properties[key] : string.Empty;
                }
                set {
                    if (_properties.ContainsKey(key)) {
                        _properties[key] = value;
                    } else {
                        _properties.Add(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }



            /// <summary>
            /// Replaces properties in the format {{propertyName}} in the source string with values from KeyValuePairPropertiesDictionarysupplied dictionary.nce you've set a property it's replaced in the string and you 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="originalStr"></param>
            /// <param name="keyValuePairPropertiesDictionary"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public override string ToString() {
                string modifiedStr = _propStr;
                foreach(var keyvaluePair in _properties) {
                    modifiedStr = modifiedStr.Replace("{{" + keyvaluePair.Key + "}}", keyvaluePair.Value);
                }

                return modifiedStr;
            }
        }



        public string _classDefinitionStr = @
        "
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

public class {{EntityName}}
{
    private SPListItem listItem;
    public {{EntityName}}_InternalProperties InternalProperties
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public {{EntityName}}(SPListItem li)
    {
        this.listItem = li;
        this.InternalProperties = new {{EntityName}}_InternalProperties(this.listItem);
    }

    {{PropertySections}}   
    public class {{EntityName}}_InternalProperties
    {
        private SPListItem listItem;

        public {{EntityName}}_InternalProperties(SPListItem li)
        {
            this.listItem = li;
        }

        {{HiddenPropertySections}}
        {{InternalPropertySections}}  
    }     
}";

        private const string _propertySectionStr = "\n\n\t" + @
        "public {{PropertyType}} {{PropertyName}}
    {   get { return listItem[Guid.Parse("
        "{{PropertyId}}"
        ")] as {{PropertyType}}; }
        set { listItem[Guid.Parse("
        "{{PropertyId}}"
        ")] = value; }}";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets string identifying the field type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="field"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetSafeTypeName(SPField field) {
            if (field.FieldValueType == null) {
                return "object"; //Not going to try to parse it further, this is enough.
            }

            var type = field.FieldValueType;

            if (type.IsValueType) {
                return type.FullName + "?";
            }
            return type.FullName;
        }

        public void GenerateForWeb(SPWeb web) {
            var blackList = new[] {
                "Documents", "Form Templates", "Site Assets", "Site Pages", "Style Library"
            };

            Directory.CreateDirectory(parentDir);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(hiddenDir);

            foreach(SPList list in web.Lists) {
                PropertyString _classDefinition = new PropertyString(_classDefinitionStr);

                string entityName = "SPL_" + list.Title.Replace(" ", "");
                _classDefinition["EntityName"] = entityName;

                foreach(SPField field in list.Fields) {
                    PropertyString propertySection = new PropertyString(_propertySectionStr);

                    propertySection["PropertyType"] = GetSafeTypeName(field); //field.FieldValueType.FullName; -> Returning Null often. Thanks, SharePoint!
                    propertySection["PropertyName"] = field.EntityPropertyName.Replace("_x0020_", "_");
                    propertySection["PropertyId"] = field.Id.ToString();

                    if (SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains(field.Id)) _classDefinition["InternalPropertySections"] += propertySection;
                    else if (field.Hidden) _classDefinition["HiddenPropertySections"] += propertySection;
                    else _classDefinition["PropertySections"] += propertySection;
                }

                if (list.Hidden || blackList.Contains(list.Title)) {
                    File.WriteAllText(hiddenDir + entityName + ".cs", _classDefinition.ToString());
                } else {
                    File.WriteAllText(parentDir + entityName + ".cs", _classDefinition.ToString());
                }
            }



        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my former employer I implemented a [DAO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) for SharePoint. Unfortunately I was not allowed to take the code with me or publish it...  I used annotations together with reflection to solve the issues with different names, optional fields, type casting etc. I also wrote a generator for the DTO-objects. But to be honest, it was a quite big effort for something that LINQ might solve in your case. Or writing your classes by hand, or writing a code generator for the getters and setters - it all depends on the size of your project(s).

Before implementing my own DAO I had a quite bad experience with LINQ to SQL, especially when columns were renamed, added or removed I didn't like the behaviour, I also had performance issues using it. That's why I prefered my own DAO pattern, but for easy tasks LINQ might be enough. My experience with LINQ also might be outdated, it was about 7 years ago ;)

Comment: This is a really interesting answer! Maybe we could implement it again? :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use an `ExpandoObject`, which is in the `System.Dynamic` namespace. Try something like this (untested):

```
public class SPListItemPropertyMapper
{
    private dynamic _expandoObject;

    public SPListItemPropertyMapper(SPListItem listItem)
    {
        _expandoObject = new ExpandoObject();
        foreach (SPField field in listItem.Fields)
        {               
            _expandoObject.Add(field.InternalName, listItem.GetFormattedValue(field.InternalName));
        }
    }

    public dynamic FieldValues
    {
        get { return _expandoObject; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
SPListItem listItem; //your list item here
var propertyMapper = new SPListItemPropertyMapper(listItem);

var title = propertyMapper.FieldValues.Title;
var editor = propertyMapper.FieldValues.Editor;
var created = propertyMapper.FieldValues.Created;
```

etc. You should consider extending the `foreach` loop by more logic, to return values based on the field type instead of just using `GetFormattedValue`.

Comment: If you're using `dynamic` then you're still not getting any compile time type checking, so you're gaining nothing over just using the `SPLIstItem`.

Comment: You're right. I'd even go with the argument to use LINQ-to-SharePoint. But at least it's an approach towards the direction the OP wanted.

Comment: And yet it doesn't actually answer the questionl, nor is it actually helpful at all.

Comment: It does not answer the question word by word, but gives a valid alternative solution. So I (and maybe the OP too) share a different opinion if it's helpful or not, than you.

Comment: How is it a valid alternate solution?  It's adding no value over just passing in a string to the `SPListItem`.  The whole point of using a POCO is to add static type checking to these fields, which is exactly what you're not giving him.  It *looks* similar while not actually adding the one piece of the puzzle that's actually important.

Comment: @Servy While you are right, please try to be nice to him, your comments come off as a bit stingy :P